# javassist - adding custom member variables

Tags: java, performance, javassist

We need to add different class member variables to a java object for each customer based on configuration. So we are using javassist to inject class members at byte code level based on config. Recently we came across an issue that for one customer we need to add more than 600 customer specific member variables. We able to make it for 600, but if we add more than 600 we are getting following error.

```
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name com.mycompany.xxxxxxxxxx.models.impl.AccountProduct
 at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
 at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forNames(ReflectionUtils.java:398)
 at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:385)
 at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:370)
 at com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at com.mycompany.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:70)
 at com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at javassist.Loader.run(Loader.java:291)
 at com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

---

```
Javassist version: 3.18.2-GA
Java version: Java 1.7
AccountProduct java class (with default non-customer specific member variables):
private Account account;
private Integer accountId;
private Product product;
private Integer productId;
private Date createdAt; 
private Date updatedAt;
private Key id;
```

Is it JVM memory related issue or is it javaassist related issue? Can anybody aware or know of this issue? Any insights? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like some sort of imposed limit... maybe group common properties into separate objects to reduce the overall number in your base class.

Comment: Looks like you use google-reflections library in `com.mycompany.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and did not configure it's classloader properly. Is `models.impl.AccountProduct` class available for default class loader? Anyway javassist works well on such amount of fields, I'm able to insert > 1000 fields.

Comment: @cjstehno I need to do this for now. we have another project in future to rewrite this implementation approach

Comment: We were able to delete some unused columns and accommodate new ones without any problem. We are planning to change the implementation in future. Not sure is there a way to close this question or mark as solved?